# Adding a Pseudo Chapter with (!) Page Number

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering

I want to manually add a chapter to the ToC and add a specific number to the page counter. This is meant for adding to my document a number of papers, which are printed out elsewhere and which I cannot add into the LaTeX file.

I tried this,

```
\newcommand{\pseudochapter}[2][0]
{
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
          {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#2}{\thepage}{}}
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{page}{#1}
}
```

However, invoking this,

```
\pseudochapter[3]{Pseudo Contents}
\chapter{Real Contents}
```

leads to output in the ToC like this,

```
Pseudo Contents ... 4
Real Contents ..... 4
```

What I expected (or wished) to find, is this,

```
Pseudo Contents ... 1
Real Contents ..... 4
```

This

```
\chapter{Real Contents}
\pseudochapter[3]{Pseudo Contents}
\chapter{Real Contents}
```

gives me

```
Real Contents ..... 1
Pseudo Contents ... 1
Real Contents ..... 5
```

when expecting

```
Real Contents ..... 1
Pseudo Contents ... 2
Real Contents ..... 5
```

I'm using KOMA class scrbook.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\newcommand{\pseudochapter}[2][0]
{
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
          {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#2}{\thepage}{}}
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{page}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \chapter{Real Contents}
    \pseudochapter[3]{Pseudo Contents}
    \chapter{Real Contents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly got it right

```
\newcommand{\pseudochapter}[2][0]
{
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
          {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#2}{\thepage}{}}
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{page}{#1}
}
```

You have to move the `\clearpage` after the `\addtocontents`, so that the `\addtocounter` won't affect the pseudo chapter.

EDIT:

To solve your new problem you can use

```
\newcommand{\pseudochapter}[2][0]
{
    \clearpage\phantom{empty}
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
        {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#2}{\thepage}{}}
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{page}{#1}
}
```

You need `\phantom` for the second `\clearpage` to work, since yor the page after the first stays clear. This command provides empty pages, so you can't use it in the middle of the first chapter (What I don't think you want).

EDIT #2:

```
\newcommand{\pseudochapter}[2][0]
{
    \newcounter{tmppage}
    \setcounter{tmppage}{\thepage}
    \stepcounter{tmppage}

    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
          {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#2}{\thetmppage}{}}
    \clearpage
    \addtocounter{page}{#1}
}
```

This way no empty pages are created **before** the command. It's not the most elegant form, but the first i could thought of. If I get a better idea, I will post it here

Comment: I must admit, this doesn't work, either. It gives me the same output. I'll update my questions with the solution you provided with further testing.

Comment: Thats strange, since I got your wanted result. Have you compiled it twice? Or could you provide a complete MWE?

Comment: I did. I also tried removing all intermediate files. I'll update my question with a MWE.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but this produces empty pages, which I would like to omit.

Comment: Great. That does the job. It may look like an ugly workaround, but I think it is the simplest and most obvious way to do this. However, you forgot the `\addtocounter{chapter}{1}` cmd. You wanna add this?